# How to generate and update a word document from a drupal content type form?

Tags: php, drupal, drupal-views, drupal-8

The concept it's:

From a Drupal 8 website, there's a content type form with multiple fields (Name, phone, address, etc, ...). Users  will fill in the fields with their personal data.

On the other side, there's a word document (in a server folder) with a preestablished text, common to all users, except for the parts where it's need to be updated with the personal user data.

For each new user, filling in the Drupal form fields, I need to generate a new word document with the preestablished text and with the exclusive text parts to each user updated .

Where do I start from?

1- How do I generate a new word document with the preestablish text from Drupal?
2- How do I update the user personal data in the word document?

Is Views export Data my only option? Do I need to make a shell script to generate a new word document for each user filling in the Drupal form fields?

Any hints?

Thank you

Comment: Ha, just re-read your post and I guess "Views export Data" was referring to Views Data Export module. I think in D8 this is your main option. In D7 you would have been able to also consider: https://www.drupal.org/project/export_doc

Answer (score 1):

First link from Google: [PHPOffice/PHPWord](https://github.com/PHPOffice/PHPWord#getting-started) - library for work with open document format. You can use it.

Comment: This is definetly an important contribution. I might have the solution just with your answer, I'll have to investigate. If it works you'll definetly get a marked answer tag.THX

Answer (score 0):

Maybe look into Views Data Export module. https://www.drupal.org/project/views_data_export

See this blog post for explanation: https://julian.pustkuchen.com/en/simply-export-html-content-doc-docx-word-document-even-simpler-pdf-generation

Comment: Just realise that question was probably referring to the same module here. This is the main option that I can think of.

Comment: I used views export data and is working as a charm. User fills in a form and I'm able to download those fields as an XLS file, then afterwards, I use a word macro template to import those files an update the user personal data in the word file. Right now this is a valid solution but as soon as the amount of users grow I will not be able or I can't be bothered to do it manually. I need to find a solution in order to have the word file generated on it's own and with the user fields data updated every time a user fills in the drupal form fields. Any hint?

Comment: Maybe use Rules module as part of the solution?

Comment: This post speaks of using cron http://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/161811/export-views-data-to-text-file-in-the-background